# Proof that $a\equiv b \pmod n \iff a \pmod n = b\pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, field-theory

Proof  that for every $a,b \in \mathbb Z,\ n \in \mathbb N$, that

$$a\equiv b \pmod n \iff a \pmod n = b \pmod n.$$

My approach is:

$n\mid a$ and $n\mid b$

$a\equiv b \pmod n \iff \exists x,y: a\cdot x+n\cdot y=b$

Then I'm stuck.

Comment: You cannot assume that $n\mid a$ and/or $n\mid b$. What are the exact definitions of the relation $\equiv_n$ and of the operator $\pmod n$ that aou are working with? Start by writing them down and staring at them a bit. - And your last staement $\exists x,y\colon\ldots$ is rather equivalent to $\gcd(a,n)\mid b$

Comment: The relation $\equiv_n$ is a mod n.

Comment: write $$a=nq+r$$ and $$b=nq'+r'$$ and proceed...

Comment: (a-r)/q=n (b-r')/q'=n

There should be a linebreak 

(a-r)*q'=(b-r')*q

Answer (score 1):

When you take a number mod $n$, you are taking its representative in $\{0,1,\dots, n-1\}$

Use the fact that $a$ (mod n) - $b$ (mod n) $\equiv a-b$ (mod n).

(To see this, say $a=m_1n +r_1$ and $b=m_2n+r_2$. Then $r_1+r_2=(a-m_1n)+(b-m_2n)$ so that $r_1+r_2\equiv a+b$ (mod n) )

Hence

$a$ (mod n) $= b$ (mod n) $\Longrightarrow$ $a$ (mod n) $-b$ (mod $n$) $=0 \Longrightarrow a-b\equiv 0$ (mod n) $\Longrightarrow a\equiv b$

Conversely, prove the contrapositive.

$a$ (mod $n$) $\not= b$ (mod $n$) $\Longrightarrow a$ (mod $n) - b$ (mod $n)\not=0 \Longrightarrow a$ (mod $n) -b$ (mod $n)\not\equiv 0$ (mod $n \Longrightarrow a-b\not\equiv 0$ (mod $n$)